# How to remove a Beep sound at the starting of an audio file?

Tags: python, signal-processing, speech-recognition, audio-processing

I have multiple audio files, all of them has a **beep** sound at the starting and then the actual audio. I want to remove that beep sound from all the files. The duration of the **beep** sound varies form file to file. Following are the methods that i have tried,

1.From the `sox` library used `trim` option by giving fixed trim duration. The problem with this is, for some of the files it removes the audio part also, as the duration of **beep** sound varies from  file to file.
eg:- `sox in.wav out.wav trim 0.15`

2.Used `pydub` library in python for detecting silenced regions in the audio, but this does not remove the **beep** part still.

3.Used `pyAudioAnalysis` library in python for detecting voice regions, but still that **beep** sound is included in the voice regions.

Is there a way in **signal processing** or any library in **python** that will do the job of suppressing the **beep** sound?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

pyAudioAnalysis contains tools that allow to train your own classifier, and then use this for segmentation. To do this, you should first create a small dataset with labeled beeps and non-beeps. You can try with just 10 examples of beep and 10 examples of non-beep, as a start.

Then follow the documentation here:
https://github.com/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis/wiki/4.-Classification-and-Regression